# Trouble Generating Avatars from Uploaded Images in OpenAI

Tags: django, openapi

I am trying to build an application in OpenAI that allows users to upload their own images and generate avatars based on those images while performing a specific activity that the user inputs. However, I am running into some issues with generating the avatars.

Whenever I upload an image and input an activity, the avatar that is generated appears distorted and does not accurately represent the original image or the activity being performed. The colors are off and the details are not crisp.

I have tried different image processing techniques such as resizing and cropping the image before generating the avatar, as well as incorporating the user's input activity into the avatar generation process, but none of them seem to improve the quality of the avatar.

I suspect that there might be some issue with the way I am generating the avatar or with the code I am using to process the image and activity input.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
import openai
import requests
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict
from django.conf import settings

openai.api_key = settings.OPENAI_API_KEY

def generate_images(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        image_file = request.FILES.get('image')
        activity1 = request.POST.get('activity1')
        activity2 = request.POST.get('activity2')

        # Construct the base URL based on the current request
        base_url = request.scheme + '://' + request.get_host() + settings.MEDIA_URL

        # Save the uploaded image to a storage location
        image_name = default_storage.save(image_file.name, ContentFile(image_file.read()))
        image_url = base_url + image_name

        prompt = f"Acting as an AI Avatar Generator, please generate two high-quality digital avatars of the activities depicted in the uploaded image found at {image_url}. The first avatar should showcase the activity '{activity1}' and the second avatar should showcase the activity '{activity2}'. The avatars should be 512x512 pixels in size and visually appealing. Please provide the URLs of the generated avatars in the response. As an informative and professional AI, accuracy and relevance of results are of utmost importance."

        headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
        headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {openai.api_key}"

        data = {
            "model": "image-alpha-001",
            "prompt": prompt,
            "size": "512x512",
            "response_format": "url",
            "n": 2
        }

        resp = requests.post("https://api.openai.com/v1/images/generations", headers=headers, json=data)

        if resp.status_code != 200:
            raise ValueError("Failed to generate image")

        response_text = resp.json()
        urls = [r["url"] for r in response_text["data"]]

        context = {
            "image1_variations": urls[0],
            "image2_variations": urls[1],
        }

        return render(request, "result.html", context)

    return render(request, "index.html")
```